# Chains of length $2^\kappa$ in ${\cal P}(\kappa)$

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, order-theory, posets

It is a fact that continues to boggle my mind: There is a set ${\cal C}\subseteq {\cal P}(\omega)$ such that $|{\cal C}|=\frak{c}=2^{\aleph_0}$ and for all $A,B\in{\cal C}$ we have $A\subseteq B$ or $B\subseteq A$. (In that case we call ${\cal C}$ a *chain*.)

The proof is remarkably easy: pick any bijection $\varphi:\omega\to\mathbb{Q}$ and consider the collection ${\cal D}$ of all down-sets of $\mathbb{Q}$. This collection forms the *Dedekind cuts* which can be used to construct $\mathbb{R}$, which has cardinality $\frak{c}$. Now $\{\varphi^{-1}(D):D\in{\cal D}\}$ is a chain in ${\cal P}(\omega)$ of cardinality $\frak{c}$.

Now you would think that you could carry the construction of $\mathbb{Q}$ and Dedekind cuts to cardinals larger than $\omega$ -- but I was not able to.

**Question.** If $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal, is there a chain  ${\cal C}\subseteq {\cal P}(\kappa)$ such that $|{\cal C}|=2^\kappa$?

Comment: I think there have been questions posted on this some time ago.

Comment: Thanks - I have tried to find one, unsuccessfully so far, and will remove this one. (It's actually well possible that it was me who asked some of the questions you are referring to...)

Comment: Don't delete yet, until we find one. But it is a common question. (One answer: if $2^{<\kappa}=\kappa$, which is a common situation, then you can use the same idea by using the lexical order on branches through $2^\kappa$.)

Comment: Just an observation:

Replacing $\mathbb{Q}$ by $\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$ also works. And that has a very natural surjection from $\mathbb{N}_{>0}\times\mathbb{N}_{>0}$. Dedekind cuts than translate to the subsets $\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}^2 \mid \frac{a}{b} < r\}$ for $r\in\mathbb{R}$.

Thinking in these terms, the question becomes whether there is a suitable way of defining "slope" in $\kappa\times\kappa$

Comment: If/when you find the answer in a different MO question, don't *delete* this one: close it as duplicate, so it will increase the likelihood of finding the answer the next time somebody wonders about this.

Comment: Trivial remark: this question is equivalent to this one: *Does there exist, for every infinite cardinal $\kappa$, a total order on $\kappa$ with $2^\kappa$ cuts?* Still equivalently: *Does there exist, for every infinite cardinal $\kappa$, a total order on $2^\kappa$ with a dense subset of cardinal $\kappa$?*

Comment: Thanks @Gro-Tsen -- let's do it that way as the question seems to be quite a natural one, as already Joel pointed out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [totally ordered chain in the powerset with big cardinality](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122031/totally-ordered-chain-in-the-powerset-with-big-cardinality) (see also comments below the question)

Comment: There's also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48231 .